# How to make a Laravel 5 Command run as a deamon

Tags: php, laravel, daemon, background-process, laravel-5

I'm building a WebSocket Server package for Laravel 5 (wrapper around [Ratchet](http://socketto.me), and for my listen command I'd like to offer the option to run it as a background daemon, so that the Ratchet loops keeps running while the user can still enter new commands (in the same way L5 provides this option for the queue:work command), however, I have no clue on how to do this, and a google search didn't help me any further.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer: don't let your script terminate.

That's somewhat more harder than it sounds, and there's a couple of ways to do that.  Some scripts will immediately [fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) into multiple processes with the 'main' one acting as the ferry of information from the sub-processes (that actually do the work) to the terminal (for output).  The downside to this approach is the increased complexity necessary for the interprocess communication to happen (setting up signal handlers and such).

All solutions that I know of more or less boil down to a continuous loop structure:

```
while(true) 
{
    doWork();
    sleep(1);
}
```

This is a daemon process.  Once started, it's always alive.  Once a second it will wake up and `doWork`.  The downside is that, once started, the only way to stop it is to break out of it (Ctrl-C) or, if started and released from the terminal (`$ php myscript.php &`) to use the really ugly hammer and `kill` it by process id.  You can get around this by registering signal handlers and having other artisan commands that send a signal to this process to terminate, and will give you a 'clean' way to shut your process down.

Another potential gotcha is, should your `doWork` method take longer than a second to run, you will no longer be having your loops execute (more or less) once a second.  This could be a problem should any sort of synchronicity be necessary.

In the context of Laravel, inside of the command's `fire` method you just need something in there (such as the infinite `while` loop) to keep the command from returning.

My advice to you, though, is not to reinvent the wheel.  WebSockets for PHP [has been solved](http://www.socketo.me/).

**Update**

If you're building a wrapper around Ratchet, then Ratchet has already solved the daemon process issue.  You just need to set up the server object and tell it to `run()`, which is what causes the *blocking* execution.  Take this example from a similar artisan command:

```
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

// Setup the Ratchet Server.
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
             $messenger
        )
    ),
    $port
);

$server->run();
// You won't reach this line unless the server crashes
```

The first bit which constructs the server I have kept in a service provider, the second bit is actually inside of an artisan command.  The `$messenger` variable there is my implementation of `Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface`.

My point here is that you don't need a daemon process in order to write a wrapper for Ratchet.  Ratchet already gives you one.

Comment: Well, what I'm building is a wrapper around Rachet for Laravel 5, to make it easier to use with a Laravel 5 project. Something in the likes of [Latchet](https://github.com/sidneywidmer/Latchet) but then for L5.

Maybe I did not clarify myself enough in my question, but what I'm actually trying to do is allow the user to enter the command in terminal, and instead of being stuck there, allow them to enter other commands. Not the only way to do that is either open a new terminal window or ctrl+c out of it (which would stop the WebSocket server)

Comment: Yes, I know this. But my question is how can I have the Laravel command be executed so the server starts running in the background, and you can enter other commands without having to either quit the process or open another terminal window? In the same way that in L5 you have the command `php artisan queue:listen` which will show output etc, and you have `php artisan queue:work connection --daemon` which runs in the background and doesn't show any output.

Comment: A bit late to this, but look into Supervisord: https://serversforhackers.com/monitoring-processes-with-supervisord